# How to solve rastertool error in QGIS 3.20

Tags: qgis, python, error

When I opened QGIS I always got this message

> Python error : Couldn't load plugin 'rastertool' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details.

That is the error it showed

```
2021-08-16T18:51:51     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in _startPlugin
              plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
              File "C:\Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\rastertool\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
              from .RasterTool import RasterTool
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\rastertool\RasterTool.py", line 54, in 
              from pyrsgis.convert import rastertocsv
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
             ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrsgis'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try to de- and re-active the plugin rastertool (or let it de-activated, if you don't use it). Does that help?

Comment: Install [`pyrsgis`](https://pypi.org/project/pyrsgis/)

Comment: https://github.com/aishwaryahegde29/RasterTool_Qgis/issues/4